# Trying to exercise with the Cont monad. Syntax issue

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

After some study ([1], [2], [3] among others) I am trying to make work of the continuation monad by attempting some examples on my own.

The second answer to [1] suggests to express the factorial using continuations. My solution is the following:

```
Cont ($ (fact 0)) = return 1
Cont ($ (fact n)) = Cont ($ (fact (n-1))) >>= (\x -> Cont ($ (n*x)))
```

I've done some simulations on paper and the solution should be correct.

However **I am unable to have it digested by GHC**. Of course I renamed the `fact` function, but still no joy.

My latest attempt is https://gist.github.com/Muzietto/595bef1815ddf375129d
and gives as always a `parse error in pattern \c -> .....`

Can anyone suggest a running implementation for these definitions?

[1] [How and why does the Haskell Cont monad work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322540/how-and-why-does-the-haskell-cont-monad-work)

[2] http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html

[3] https://wiki.haskell.org/MonadCont_under_the_hood

Comment: first: the gist is fine in itself but why don't you copy&paste the code in here - it's just convenient for us trying to help out here - next I don't think your types match up (or I guess wrong what you are trying to do) - have you tried to solve this problem just with continuation-passing-style (you don't exactly need the monad/`Cont`-wrapper to understand the technique)?

Comment: @carsten - This attempt of mine arises indeed from a perfectly working CPS implementation, definitely too trivial to mention. I believe it's clear that the whole point of this question is about using the monad, and especially its bind function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can not define a function in the way you posted for the same reason you can not implement a predecessor function as follows:

```
1 + (predecessor x) = x
```

Functions can only be defined through equations of the form

```
f pattern1 .. patternK = expression
```

Note that `f` must be found at the top-level.

For your factorial function using the continuation monad, you can simplify your attempt as follows:

```
fact :: Int -> Cont r Int
-- Your own code:
-- Cont ($ (fact 0)) = return 1
fact 0 = return 1
-- Cont ($ (fact n)) = Cont ($ (fact (n-1))) >>= (\x -> Cont ($ (n*x)))
fact n = fact (n-1) >>= \x -> return (n*x)

-- the "real" factorial function, without monads
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial n = runCont (fact n) id
```

Note that `return (n*x)` above is indeed `Cont ($ (n*x))`, but I think it's more readable in the former way, also because it does not break the abstraction. Indeed, it would work in *any* monad once written as above.

Alternatively, use `do` notation.

```
fact :: Int -> Cont r Int
fact 0 = return 1
fact n = do
   x <- fact (n-1)
   return (n*x)
```

Or use a functor operator:

```
fact :: Int -> Cont r Int
fact 0 = return 1
fact n = (n*) <$> fact (n-1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I suspected I was doing something not-haskellian in my code :-) I am keen in getting a feel for 'bind', hoping to bring abstraction to a higher level. I appreciated the thoroughness and completeness of your answer. The functor version is mind-blowing. Gotta spend some time thinking about this fmap.

Comment: @Muzietto Monads are required to be "compatible" with their functor instance in the sense that they must satisfy the law `fmap f x = x >>= (return . f)`. Basically and informally, if you get something out of the monad (`>>=`), apply some `f` and then put it back in the monad with `return`, the result should be the same of `fmap f`.

Comment: yes I am aware of the relationship between functors and monads, but I've always considered `bind` to be on a higher level of abstraction (and capabilities) than `fmap`. Seeing `fmap` here do more or less the same job in an even terser syntax is quite surprising.