# How does continuation monad really work

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I understand how Reader or Maybe or State monads work, but havig hard times with Continuations monad.
Examples like below, blow my head

```
type ContinuationMonad() =
   member this.Bind (m, f) = fun c -> m (fun a -> f a c)
   member this.Return x = fun k -> k x
```

I think that my problem is that I cannot get what is a monadic type for Continuation (like Cont<'T>) and how i can unwrap it and wrap back.
Any helpful examples or links are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is covered at great length [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322540/how-and-why-does-the-haskell-cont-monad-work), especially @C. A. McCann's answer deserves attention (and possibly a reread or two).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will not repeat what has been said elsewhere - the post mentioned in the comments gives a lot of details about the continuation monad. But one thing that might help is to rewrite your code snippet with an explicit definition for `Cont<'T>`:

```
type Cont<'T> = 
  Cont of (('T -> unit) -> unit)
```

The type `Cont<'T>` represents a computation. You can *start* it by giving it a function `'T -> unit` that takes the result and does something with it (say, prints it). When you start it, it returns `unit` and it will (at some point) produce a value `'T` and call the *continuation* you provided.

With this more explicit definition, the builder can be defined as:

```
type ContinuationMonad() =
   member this.Bind (ma, f) = 
      Cont(fun k -> 
        let (Cont ca) = ma
        ca (fun a -> 
            let (Cont cb) = f a
            cb k))

   member this.Return x = 
      Cont(fun k -> k x)
```

- The `Return` member creates a computation that, when given a continuation `k`, calls this continuation immediately with the value `x` that we returned.
- The `Bind` member returns a new computation that, when given a continuation `k`, starts the computation specified by `m`; when this computation produces a value `a`, it calls the function `f` and *then* calls the computation returned by `f` with the original continuation `k` (which is the "final" continuation that should eventually be called with the final result).

Comment: As a monad newbie, this helped me a lot. I expanded it a bit below.

Answer (score 4):

I found Tomas's answer helpful, with a few important caveats:

- Using the name `Cont` to represent a computation is IMHO confusing
  because it suggests (incorrectly) that a `Cont` is a contination. I
  propose to use the name `Inc` instead, because it represents an
  "incomplete" computation. This computation contains a value (of type
  `'T`) that it is ready to pass on to a continuation. **Important point**:
  An `Inc` is not the same thing as a continuation.
- I would also propose to define `Inc` without the pattern matching
  overhead of a discriminated union. This simplifies the implementation
  of `Bind` considerably.
- I'm also not sure why we should assume that a continuation always
  produces `unit`, but it certainly simplifies things considerably, so
  I'll keep this assumption in what follows.

So, we can define a continuation as any function with a signature of `'T -> unit`, and we can define `Inc` as:

```
type Inc<'T> = 
    ('T -> unit) -> unit
```

In English, an `Inc` passes its wrapped `'T` value to a given continuation function, resulting in `unit`.

Next, we need an explicit signature for the `Bind` function. Because it's a monad, we know it has to look like this:

```
let bind (inc : Inc<'T>) (wrap : 'T -> Inc<'U>) : Inc<'U> =
```

So `bind` takes an incomplete computation (of type `'T`) and a function that can "wrap" a raw value in an incomplete computation (of type `'U`), and returns a new incomplete computation of that type. Based on this signature, we know that `bind` has to return an `Inc`, and an `Inc` is a function that takes a continuation as input. So we know that implementation of `bind` has to start like this:

```
    fun (cont : 'U -> unit) -> ...
```

Our job is to extract the `'T` value that's wrapped inside the given `Inc`, and then re-wrap it using the given wrapper function. **Key insight**: The only way to obtain this value is to ask the `Inc` to pass it to us via a continuation that we'll now write! Inside this "artificial" continuation, we re-wrap the extracted value and give it back to the caller. The completed `bind` function therefore looks like this:

```
let bind (inc : Inc<'T>) (wrap : 'T -> Inc<'U>) : Inc<'U> =
    fun (cont : 'U -> unit) ->   // return an Inc, which is a function that takes a continuation as input
        inc (fun t ->            // force the incomplete computation to cough up its wrapped value
            (wrap t) cont)       // wrap the raw value so it can be sent to the given continuation
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I found the Haskell name and definition of `Cont` quite hard to grok!

A direct translation from Haskell is also not ideal with F# type-inference - you will often you need to manually add a generic parameter for the return type.

So with that in mind, here is an alternative implementation that may clear things up.

An `IContinuationChain<'a>` object represents a series of function calls in continuation-passing style that ends in an `'a` value. The series can be completed by passing in a final continuation.

Here is the interface definition:

```ml
type IContinuationChain<'a> =
  abstract member Complete<'r> : continuation : ('a -> 'r) -> 'r
```

The Haskell equivalent, `Cont`, is:

```hs
newtype Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }
```

Note how the `'r` type parameter is moved down to the method level. This is because it is the caller who decides what kind `'r` should be. This plays nicely with F# type-inference, requiring fewer annotations.

For working with `IContinuationChain<'a>` values, you can use these core functions:

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module ContinuationChain =

  let startFrom (value : 'a) : IContinuationChain<'a> =
    {
      new IContinuationChain<'a> with
        member this.Complete<'r>(continuation : 'a -> 'r) =
          continuation value
    }

  let extend (f : 'a -> IContinuationChain<'b>) (m : IContinuationChain<'a>) : IContinuationChain<'b> =
    {
      new IContinuationChain<'b> with
        member this.Complete<'r>(continuation : 'b -> 'r) =
          m.Complete(f).Complete(continuation)
    }

  let complete (continuation : 'a -> 'r) (m : IContinuationChain<'a>) : 'r =
    m.Complete(continuation)

  let run (m : IContinuationChain<'a>) : 'a =
    m.Complete(id)
```

*Type annotations added for clarity*

From these, we can construct a Computation Expression:

```ml
type ContinuationChainBuilder() =
  member this.Return(x) =
    ContinuationChain.startFrom x

  member this.Bind(m, f) =
    ContinuationChain.extend f m

let continuationChain = ContinuationChainBuilder()
```

Usage example:

```ml
let rec fibonacci (n : int) =
  continuationChain {
    match n with
    | 0 -> return 0
    | 1 -> return 1
    | _ ->
      let! x = fibonacci (n - 1)
      let! y = fibonacci (n - 2)

      return x + y
  }

for n in 0..9 do
  let r = ContinuationChain.run (fibonacci n)

  printfn $"fibonacci %i{n} = %i{r}"
```

```
fibonacci 0 = 0
fibonacci 1 = 1
fibonacci 2 = 1
fibonacci 3 = 2
fibonacci 4 = 3
fibonacci 5 = 5
fibonacci 6 = 8
fibonacci 7 = 13
fibonacci 8 = 21
fibonacci 9 = 34
```

Hopefully that makes sense!

We can then map these concepts back to `Cont`:

- `IContinuationChain<'a>` is equivalent to `Cont<r, a>`
- `ContinuationChain.startFrom` is equivalent to `pure` in the `Cont` monad
- `ContinuationChain.extend` is equivalent to `bind` in the `Cont` monad
- `ContinuationChain.complete` is equivalent to `runCont`