# On nested CPS suspension types

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, continuation-passing, higher-rank-types

Let's begin with the familiar type of CPS suspended computations, `(a -> r) -> r`, spelled as `Cont r a` in *mtl*-speak. We know that [it is isomorphic to `a` as long as it is kept polymorphic in `r`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45287954/2751851). If we nest this type, we get this rank-3 type:

```
forall r. ((forall s. (a -> s) -> s) -> r) -> r
```

(For the sake of convenience, I might have defined `type Susp a = forall r. (a -> r) -> r` and then began talking about `Susp (Susp a)`, but I fear that would lead to distracting technicalities.)

We can get a similar type by universally quantifying the result type only after nesting, as it would be if we had `forall r. Cont r (Cont r a)`:

```
forall r. (((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
```

Is there any meaningful difference between these two types? I say meaningful because some things that can apparently be only done with the first, "SuspSusp" type...

```
GHCi> foo = (\kk -> kk (\k -> k True)) :: forall s. ((forall r. (Bool -> r) -> r) -> s) -> s
GHCi> bar = (\kk -> kk (\k -> k True)) :: forall r. (((Bool -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
GHCi> foo (\m -> show (m not))
"False"
GHCi> bar (\m -> show (m not))

<interactive>:76:12: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Bool'
      Expected type: Bool
        Actual type: String
    * In the expression: show (m not)
      In the first argument of `bar', namely `(\ m -> show (m not))'
      In the expression: bar (\ m -> show (m not))
```

... can also be achieved with the second, "ContCont" one by taking advantage of the free theorem for `(a -> r) -> r`, `f (m g) = m (f . g)` for any `m :: (a -> r) -> r`.

```
GHCi> foo (\m -> m (show . not))
"False"
GHCi> bar (\m -> m (show . not))
"False"
```

Comment: Since `Susp a` is isomorphic to `a`, it follows that `Susp (Susp a)` is also isomorphic to `a`. So your question then boils down to whether `forall r. Cont r (Cont r a)` is isomorphic to `a`.

Comment: I don't understand your statement of the free theorem. Can you clarify which variables are supposed to be quantified?

Comment: @TwanvanLaarhoven Yup, that's another way of looking at it. (Originally, I was wondering about `Cont r (Cont r a)` versus `Susp a`; I then switched to the formulation in this post hoping that it might bring some extra clarity.)

Comment: @dfeuer `r` is quantified; with `g :: a -> r` and `f :: r -> s`. (I probably should have written `(A -> r) -> r`, for the sake of clarity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely confident about the following take on the matter (it kinda feels too good to be true), but it is the best I have to offer up to now, so let's put it on the table.

[chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052068/2751851) tackles the problem by proposing an isomorphism candidate between `a` and `forall r. (((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r`:

```
-- If you want to play with these in actual code, make YD a newtype.
type YD a = forall r. (((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r

ydosi :: a -> YD a
ydosi x = \kk -> kk (\k -> k x)

ydiso :: YD a -> a
ydiso mm = mm (\m -> m id)
```

chi then proves `ydiso . ydosi = id`, which leaves the `ydosi . ydiso` direction to be dealt with.

Now, if we have some `f` and its left inverse `g` (`g . f = id`), it readily follows that `f . g . f = f`. If `f` is surjective, we can "cancel" it on the right, leading us to `f . g = id` (i.e. the other direction of the isomorphism). That being so, given that we have `ydiso . ydosi = id`, establishing that `ydosi` is surjective will be enough to prove the isomorphism. One way of looking into that is reasoning about the inhabitants of `YD a`.

(Though I won't attempt to do that here, I presume the following passages can be made precise by expressing them in terms of the System F typing rules -- [cf. this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40155/380202).)

An `YD A` value is a function that takes a continuation:

```
mm :: forall r. (((A -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
mm = \kk -> _y
-- kk :: forall r. ((A -> r) -> r) -> r
-- _y :: r
```

The only way to get a result of type `r` here is by applying `kk` to something:

```
mm :: forall r. (((A -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
mm = \kk -> kk _m
-- kk :: forall r. ((A -> r) -> r) -> r
-- _m :: forall r. (A -> r) -> r
```

As the type of `kk` is polymorphic in `r`, so must be the type of `_m`. That means we also know what `_m` must be like, thanks to the familiar `A`/`forall r. (A -> r) -> r` isomorphism:

```
mm :: forall r. (((A -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
mm = \kk -> kk (\k -> k _x)
-- kk :: forall r. ((A -> r) -> r) -> r
-- k :: forall r. (A -> r) -> r
-- _x :: A
```

The right-hand side above, however, is precisely `ydosi`:

```
mm :: forall r. (((A -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
mm = ydosi _x
-- _x :: A
```

We have just found out that any `forall r. (((A -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r` value is `ydosi x` for some `x :: A`. It immediately follows that `ydosi` is surjective, which is enough to prove the isomorphism.

Since `a` is isomorphic to `forall r. ((forall s. (a -> s) -> s) -> r) -> r` (cf. [Twan van Laarhoven's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045098/on-nested-cps-suspension-types#comment87110867_50045098)) and to `forall r. (((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r`, transitivity means both nested suspension types are isomorphic.

---

What do the witnesses of the nested suspension isomorphism look like? If we define...

```
-- The familiar isomorphism.
type Susp a = forall r. (a -> r) -> r

suosi :: a -> Susp a
suosi x = \k -> k x

suiso :: Susp a -> a
suiso m = m id
```

... we can write...

```
ydosi . suiso . suiso :: Susp (Susp a) -> YD a
suosi . suosi . ydiso :: YD a -> Susp (Susp a)
```

... which boils down to:

```
-- A few type annotations would be necessary to persuade GHC about the types here.
\mm -> \kk -> kk (\k -> k (mm id id)) -- Susp (Susp a) -> YD a
\mm -> \kk -> kk (\k -> k (mm (\m -> m id))) -- YD a -> Susp (Susp a)
```

We can apply the `Susp a` free theorem on `mm` in the first witness...

```
f (mm g) = mm (f . g) -- Free theorem
f (mm id) = mm f

mm id id
($ id) (mm id)
mm ($ id)
mm (\m -> m id)
```

... and so:

```
\mm -> \kk -> kk (\k -> k (mm (\m -> m id))) -- Susp (Susp a) -> YD a
\mm -> \kk -> kk (\k -> k (mm (\m -> m id))) -- YD a -> Susp (Susp a)
```

Fascinatingly, the witnesses are "the same" except for their types. I wonder if there some argument starting from this observation would allow us to proceed backwards and prove the isomorphism in a more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

(partial answer)

I wouldn't be surprised if `a` turned up to be isomorphic to your proposed type

```
forall r. (((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r
```

So far, I was only able to prove that the former embeds into the latter. The embedding could as well be an isomorphism, but if that holds, to prove that we will likely need to exploit parametricity on the scary type above.

Here's the embedding:

```
type YD a = forall r. (((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r

ydosi :: a -> YD a
ydosi x = \f -> f (\g -> g x)

ydiso :: YD a -> a
ydiso x = x (\a -> a id)
```

Proving that this is an embedding is easy, and only requires beta steps:

```
ydiso (ydosi x)
= ydiso (\f -> f (\g -> g x))
= (\f -> f (\g -> g x)) (\a -> a id)
= (\a -> a id) (\g -> g x)
= (\g -> g x) id
= id x
= x
```

The opposite direction is much harder, and (if possible) should rely on the parametricity of `x :: YD a`. Completing this would prove the wanted isomorphism.

```
ydosi (ydiso x)
= ydosi (x (\a -> a id))
= \f -> f (\g -> g (x (\a -> a id)))
= ????
= x
```

Comment: Yup -- the harder direction feels so close, yet so far... I wonder if showing either that `ydiso` is injective or that `ydosi` is surjective (which, I believe, should be enough to get the other direction given the one we already have), though it probably requires parametricity in a similar way.

Comment: After quite a while, I have grown confident enough in my attempt to wiggle out of this bind to post it as [a complementary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885488/2751851). I'd love to hear your take on it.